# appending each input to the closet form , not working for me

Tags: jquery

I can't get this working , trying to append each input to the closet form

example html

set up a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/5fp9jpmk/

any help appreciated

```
 <form>
<ol type="a">
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="accept"> Yes</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="counter_proposal"> No</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="reject"> Reject</li>
</ol>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Respond To Trade Offer" id="trade_button1">

<form>
<ol type="a">
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="accept"> Yes</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="counter_proposal"> No</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="reject"> Reject</li>
</ol>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Respond To Trade Offer" id="trade_button2">

<form>
<ol type="a">
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="accept"> Yes</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="counter_proposal"> No</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="reject"> Reject</li>
</ol>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Respond To Trade Offer" id="trade_button3">

<form>
<ol type="a">
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="accept"> Yes</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="counter_proposal"> No</li>
<li><input type="radio" name="ACTION" value="reject"> Reject</li>
</ol>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Respond To Trade Offer" id="trade_button4">
```

Tried this

```
jQuery("input[type='submit']").each(function () {
  $(this).closest('form').append(this);
});
```

Comment: `closest()` looks for elements that are **parents** of the element in the dom.  The submit button is not a child of any of those forms.  What you are after with your given dom layout is the `prev('form')` of the input

Comment: Just exactly what are you trying to do by appending a button to the form? Why aren't they children of their respective forms in the first place?

Comment: Just change it to `$(this).prev('form').append(this)` should work: https://jsfiddle.net/ybotwzLL/

Comment: no idea why the website they have created has the buttons outside the forms , but it does , probably the reason they dont work , i don't have html access , so looking for a jquery fix to inject in footer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, @Taplar is right, I think you're looking is `prev()`

```
jQuery("input[type='submit']").each(function () {
  $(this).prev().append(this);
});
```

Keep in mind this work as long as the html hierarchy remains the same. Prev is just searching for the previous html node, which in this case it's a form. Curious question here, why the submit button is not part of the form in the first place :)?